# Intune Graph API assign Managed App Policy

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a Powershell script to assign managed app policy to a group. So I have a function Assign-ManagedAppPolicy that takes Application polici id ($AppID) and JSON constructed to represent a body of POST request and group ID of a group that should be assigned. But I constantly get an error:

```
    Assign-ManagedAppPolicy -AppID $AppID -JSON $GroupJS -GroupID $GroupID -Verbose 

   VERBOSE: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/Beta/managedAppPolicies/T_216bea0a-f02c-42ee-a0b3-8c0266d615bf/updateTargetedSecurityGroups with -1-byte payload`
```

Response content:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'updateTargetedSecurityGroups'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "1a183b97-668b-41ca-9d97-dda6cd839249",
      "date": "2017-05-25T15:45:37"
    }
  }
}
Assign-ManagedAppPolicy : Request to https://graph.microsoft.com/Beta/managedAppPolicies/T_216bea0a-f02c-42ee-a0b3-8c0266d615bf/updateTargetedSecurityGroups failed with HTTP Status BadRequest Bad Request
At line:1 char:1
+ Assign-ManagedAppPolicy -AppID $AppID -JSON $GroupJS -GroupID $GroupI ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Assign-ManagedAppPolicy
```

Any guess?

My function:

```
    Function Assign-ManagedAppPolicy()

    {

    <#
    .SYNOPSIS

    This function is used to assign an Managed App policy using the Graph API REST interface

    .DESCRIPTION`

    The function connects to the Graph API Interface and assigns a Managed App policy

    .EXAMPLE

    Assign-ManagedAppPolicy -AppID $AppID -JSON $JSON

    Assigns a Managed App policy in Intune

    .NOTES

    NAME: Assign-ManagedAppPolicy

    #>

    [cmdletbinding()]

    param

  (

$AppID,
$JSON, 
$GroupID
    )

   $graphApiVersion = "Beta"

   $Resource = "managedAppPolicies"

try {

    if($AppID -eq "" -or $AppID -eq $null -or $JSON -eq "" -or $JSON -eq $null){

    write-host "No Parameters specified, please specify valid AppID and GroupID for a Managed App Policy..." -f Red

    }

    else {

            Test-JSON -JSON $JSON        

    $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/$graphApiVersion/$($Resource)/$($AppID)/updateTargetedSecurityGroups"

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authToken -Method POST -Body $JSON -ContentType "application/json"

    }

}

catch {

Write-Host

$ex = $_.Exception

$errorResponse = $ex.Response.GetResponseStream()

$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($errorResponse)

$reader.BaseStream.Position = 0

$reader.DiscardBufferedData()

$responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();

Write-Host "Response content:`n$responseBody" -f Red

Write-Error "Request to $Uri failed with HTTP Status $($ex.Response.StatusCode) $($ex.Response.StatusDescription)"

write-host

break

}

   }
```

Program body:

```
    # Assign MAM Policy to group

    $AppID

    $GroupID

    $GroupJS =  @{"TargetedSecurityGroups"= ,@{"@odata.type"="#microsoft.graph.directoryObject";"id"=$($GroupID)}} | ConvertTo-Json
```